# Why is my ModelState valid if I pass an object with no value for a required property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, modelstate

I create an "invalid" restaurant in my test and pass it to the Post method. In the Post method I validate the modelstate and it says it is valid. Any help is appreciated!

Domain Class:

```
[Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Test:

```
var invalidRestaurant = new Restaurant { City = "TEST", Id =1 };
var actionResult = _sut.Post(invalidRestaurant) as BadRequestResult;
Assert.NotNull(actionResult);
```

ModelState if-statement that doesn't get entered:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Comment: Is this MVC or Web API?

Comment: This is a Web API

Comment: you haven't gone thru the pipeline to validate the model